# How to use eloquent ->with method on collection

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-collection

You may find the question stupid. I may not be doing the research well so I thought to ask it here. I would like to know how to use ->with on collection or what is its equivalent. Here is the code:

```
$theLastCommentOfThisPost = $post->comments->with('user')->sortByDesc('id')->first();
```

I would like to get something like this:

```
Illuminate\Support\Collection Object
(
    [items:protected] => Array
        (
            [id] => 19
            [commentable_type] => App\Post
            [commentable_id] => 123
            [comment] => totoototo
            [is_approved] => 1
            [user_id] => 1
            [created_at] => 2019-04-01
            [updated_at] => 2020-02-04
            [user] => App\User Object
                    (
                        [id] => 1
                        [name] => App\Post
                        [email] => totos@toto.fr
                    )
        )

)
```

thanks

Comment: @RobBiermann I do not have other specific query. I just want to get this collection. And I am trying to write optimal or best query. thank you

Comment: I mean where is the query that gets your $post?

Comment: Because what you would need is something like: `$post = Post::with('comments.user')->get()`

Comment: oh nothing special. $post = Post::find($request->post_id); so simple.

Comment: Then it should be `$post = Post::with('comments.user')->find($request->post_id);`

Comment: Oook I see, but in my context I don't want to this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to "load" relationships for a Collection of Models you would use the `load` method.

```
$post->comments->load('user')->.....
```

Though to not have to load all the comments to only get one you can do this with a query:

```
$post->comments()->with('user')->latest()->first();
```

Not really sure overall the data you need besides this one object.

[Laravel 5.8 Docs - Eloquent Collections - Available Methods - `load`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-collections#available-methods)

Comment: I think it will work. I am just getting  Call to undefined relationship [user] on model [BeyondCode\Comments\Comment] due to the package I am using. I will try to get answer for this in order discussion. thank you. you teach me great thing!